monologBundle records message 2 times
On a symfony project version 5.4, i have a strange behavior with monologBundle.
Monolog record the message twice as we can see on the picture below.
I am using channels and handlers as below


monolog: 
    channels: ['channel_starcloud']
    handlers:
        starcloudHandler:
            channels: ['channel_starcloud']
            level: debug
            type: rotating_file
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/webhook/starcloud/%kernel.environment%.log"
            max_files: 30




config/packages/prod/monolog.yaml
config/packages/dev/monolog.yaml


I have this behavior only on the production and staging.
On local, i cannot simulate this issue. and also when i set APP_ENV variable to prod.
Any ideas?

Is there a double configuration thats logs the same. Check the config/package directory and in de config/package/prod directory
config/package/monolog.yaml
config/package/prod/monolog.yaml
Those files are merged together based on the running environment
